# Resolving the conflict when the file on disk has been changed

Tags: saving, buffer-modified

When a file changes on disk while you're editing in Emacs, how to merge both sets of changes into the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're familiar with `ediff` you can also:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `ediff-current-file`

> Start ediff between current buffer and its file on disk.
>   This command can be used instead of `revert-buffer'.  If there is
>   nothing to revert then this command fails.

I have both this and a custom `diff-buffer-with-file` variant bound to keys, as I use them quite frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I manually resolve the conflict as follows:

- `write-file` the buffer visiting the original file to a temporary file
- `ediff-merge-files` the original file and the temporary file
- When finished, quit Ediff and confirm when it asks whether to kill buffer A and B.
- `write-file` buffer B (`*ediff-merge*`) to the original file